# Inherit Union type in Python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.10

Say that we create a generic [Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) type called `ResultData` in **Python 3.10**

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Union
from typing import _SpecialForm, _GenericAlias

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Error:
    description: str

S = TypeVar('S')
ResultData = S | Error
```

Note that in this case, I am using the [new Python 3.10 Union syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html)

Then the problem comes when trying to inherit the class to add a few methods (like the ones from a Monad):

```
T = TypeVar('T')
class Result(ResultData[T]):
    def __init__(self):
```

By declaring this class, it throws the following error:

```
    class Result(ResultData[T]):
TypeError: _SpecialForm.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

It seems that Union types inherit from the following two classes:`_SpecialForm` and `_GenericAlias`.

`_GenericAlias` has 4 arguments as constructor, while `_SpecialForm` has only two.
My *guess* is that `_SpecialForm` constructor is called using `_GenericAlias` constructor and thus that causes the error.

I tried to fix that with the following code:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')
class Result(ResultData[T]):
    def __init__(self):
        super(_SpecialForm, self).__init__(self._getitem)
        super(_GenericAlias, self).__init__(self.origin, self.params, self.inst, self.name)
```

Yet I still get the same error.

Comment: What do you expect a subclass of a union to even mean? Unions aren't Unions at runtime, the runtime object is one of the alternative types. I don't think you can inherit from a `TypeVar` either.

Comment: Inheriting from a TypeVar has been successful. Regarding your Union question, I expect that whatever object is at runtime, that object would inherit functionality from the subclass.

Comment: Are you looking for `class Result(Generic[T]):`? What you're doing is more like `class Result(T):` which doesn't work.